# Linq to NHibernate projection to anon. type results in mystifying cast error

Tags: linq, anonymous-types, linq-to-nhibernate, projection

I have an TaxWork entity which is persisted using NHibernate. This entity has the following properties (among others):

```
public virtual TaxWorkType Type { get; set; } //Kctc.TaxWorkType is an enumeration
public virtual TaxWorkStatus Status { get; set; } //Kctc.TaxWorkStatus is an enumeration
public virtual LegalWorkPriority Priority { get; set; } //Kctc.LegalWorkType is an enumeration
public virtual User Handler { get; set; } //Kctc.BusinessLayer.Entities.User is another entity
public virtual int? CaseNumber { get; set; }
```

I am using Linq to NHibernate to pull of a subset of the tax work objects as follows (taxWorkRepository.All obviously returns an IQueryable):

```
foreach (TaxWork taxWork in taxWorkRepository.All.Where(x => x.CaseNumber == _caseNumber).OrderBy(x => x.DateCreated))
{
    ...
}
```

This works fine. I want to use projection in order to query only the columns that are required in this case. I am usnig the following code:

```
foreach (var taxWorkFragment in taxWorkRepository.All.Where(x => x.CaseNumber == _caseNumber).OrderBy(x => x.DateCreated).Select(x => new { Type = x.Type, DateCreated = x.DateCreated, Handler = x.Handler, Status = x.Status, Priority = x.Priority }))
{
    ...
}
```

However, I'm getting the following error when trying to create the anonymous type:

Invalid cast from 'Kctc.TaxWorkStatus' to 'Kctc.BusinessLayer.Entities.User'.

Where on earth is it getting the idea that it should be casting a TaxWorkStatus to a User?

Any suggestions whatsoever what might be going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try to make like this:

```
foreach (var taxWorkFragment in taxWorkRepository.All.Where(x => x.CaseNumber == _caseNumber).OrderBy(x => x.DateCreated)
.Select(x => new TaxWork { Type = x.Type, DateCreated = x.DateCreated, Handler = x.Handler, Status = x.Status, Priority = x.Priority }))
{
...
}
```

It should help